# Android: Handler with MainLooper : "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Tags: android, handler

From my generic **fragment**, I have this method:

```
protected void loadDataListWithDelay() {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadDataList();
            }
        }, DELAY_START_LOADING);
    }
```

This method allows to start a new loading data from server (with Volley networking).

In my loadDataList() method there are some views visibility setting:

```
protected void loadDataList(String url, ArrayList<BaseFilters> filters,
                                String query, boolean byPassSearchMode) {
      ...
      mLoadingDataListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      mListContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ...
```

This code runs perfectly, but I have this crash this morning on mobile with Android 6.0.1.

Could you help me guys?

Comment: I guess one obvious question is that, is there a chance that any of the Views in the Fragment could be created off the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a good advice, if you want to do postDelayed, take a view in your fragment (or any view), and do postDelayed with it. i.e. textView.postDelayed(.. This way you can be sure you are on the ui thread.

Comment: But with new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); is not enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use runOnUiThread instead of creating a new handler ?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadDataList();
    }
});
```

If you need a delay, then you can use a handler inside the runOnUiThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadDataList();
            }
        }, DELAY);
    }
});
```

Comment: postDelayed is not post

Comment: So, guys, what is the best way: user1940343 or Uriel Frankel ?

Comment: You can do it either way. I believe runOnUiThread() is a cleaner solution to post updates on UI thread.